# How can I toggle text with shortcode using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shortcode

My goal is after clicking the piece of the pie it would automatically scrolls down and activate the read more to show the description for that pie. I can't use jquery inside this shortcode because it was separated from the view. I tried adding the `class="toggle-text-button"`inside the chart but it didn't work
Shortcode for the pie chart

```
function pie_chart( $atts, $content="" ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(), $atts, 'pie_chart');
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<div class="big-pie">';
        $html .= '<a href="#first" toggle-text="1"><div id="slice-1" class="hold"><span>First</span></div></a>';
        $html .= '<a href="#second" toggle-text="2"><div id="slice-2" class="hold"><span>Second</span></div></a>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;
}
```

Read more view

```
<!-- First -->
<div id="first">
    <h3 class="py-3">First</h3>
    <p>Shown Texts.</p>
    <p class="toggle-text" id="toggle-text-1">Hidden Texts.</p>
    <a class="toggle-text-button" toggle-text="1">Read More</a>
</div>
<!-- Second -->
<div id="first">
    <h3 class="py-3">Second</h3>
    <p>Shown Texts.</p>
    <p class="toggle-text" id="toggle-text-2">Hidden Texts.</p>
    <a class="toggle-text-button" toggle-text="2">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Script for scrolling down after clicking the pie

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        },1000);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

To read more and view more texts

```
<script type="text/javascript">// Add click event dynamically
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document).on("click", ".toggle-text-button", function() {

          if ($(this).text() == "Read More") {

            $(this).text("Read Less");

            // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
            $("#toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text")).slideDown();

          } else {

            $(this).text("Read More");

            // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
            $("#toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text")).slideUp();

          }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So you don't have problem with scroll or show/hide the text you just want the text to show after scroll? right?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes you're right. It's like calling the read more script after doing the scroll script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>If you just want the text to show (the button to trigger click) after scroll</sup> You can use `.animate` callback function then use `.find()` to find the button then `.click` to trigger the click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
        var The_Element = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: The_Element.offset().top
        },1000 , function(){
            The_Element.find('.toggle-text-button:not(".clicked")').click(); // or .trigger('click') // .toggle-text-button:not(".clicked")
        });
        return false;
     });
</script>
```

**Additional Notes:**

- Use `$('a[href^="#"]')` the anchor which its hrefs starts with `#` because `$('a')` will select all anchors
- No need to work with `attr` its enough to use `$(this).prev('p.toggle-text')`
- It'll be better to work with `add/removeClass` in the button click to prevent the click after animation to hide the text if its already shown

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">// Add click event dynamically
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document).on("click", ".toggle-text-button", function() {

          if ($(this).text() == "Read More") {

            $(this).addClass('clicked').text("Read Less"); //.addClass('clicked')

            // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
            $(this).prev('p.toggle-text').slideDown();

          } else {

            $(this).removeClass('clicked').text("Read More"); // .removeClass('clicked')

            // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
            $(this).prev('p.toggle-text').slideUp();

          }

        });
    });
</script>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var The_Element = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: The_Element.offset().top
    },1000 , function(){
        The_Element.find('.toggle-text-button:not(".clicked")').click(); // or .trigger('click') // .toggle-text-button:not(".clicked")
    });
    return false;
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".toggle-text-button", function(){
    if ($(this).text() == "Read More") {
      $(this).addClass('clicked').text("Read Less"); //.addClass('clicked')
      // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
      $(this).prev('p.toggle-text').slideDown();
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('clicked').text("Read More"); // .removeClass('clicked')
      // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
      $(this).prev('p.toggle-text').slideUp();
    }
  });

})
```

```css
body *{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
.big-pie{
  position : fixed;
  top : 0;
  background : red;
  right : 0;
}
.big-pie > a{
  display : inline-block;
  color : #fff;
  padding : 5px;
}

.TheElement{
  height : 500px;
}
.toggle-text{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-pie">'
  <a href="#first"><div id="slice-1" class="hold"><span>First</span></div></a>
  <a href="#second"><div id="slice-2" class="hold"><span>Second</span></div></a>
</div>

<div style="height : 1000px;"></div>

<!-- First -->
<div id="first" class="TheElement">
    <h3 class="py-3">First</h3>
    <p>Shown Texts.</p>
    <p class="toggle-text">Hidden Texts.</p>
    <a class="toggle-text-button">Read More</a>
</div>
<!-- Second -->
<div id="second" class="TheElement">
    <h3 class="py-3">Second</h3>
    <p>Shown Texts.</p>
    <p class="toggle-text">Hidden Texts.</p>
    <a class="toggle-text-button">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `The_Element.find` is this the part where I put the read more function? Sorry I'm not really good with javascript or jquery

Comment: @newbie no need to add functions or repeat the code .. `.click()` in my code will trigger the button click for you .. please try my code as it is and It should work

Comment: Sorry it's not working on my local. How does the it tell to open which description after clicking the right pie? Like if I click the 2nd pie, the 2nd description would activate read more

Comment: @newbie look after you click on `a` which has href `#first` by `The_Element = $($(this).attr('href'));` The_Element will be `$('#first')` and with `.find('.toggle-text-button')` the code will search inside the `$('#first')` to find `.toggle-text-button` and by using `.click` it will trigger the click handler for this  `.toggle-text-button`

Comment: Hey it's working but it only change the read more into read less. It's not showing the description

Comment: @newbie see the snippet above .. I didn't change anything in my code I just copy/paste it and use some css

Comment: @newbie No need to use `toggle-text=` attribute at all .. I remove it from my snippet .. check it

Comment: You're totally welcome @newbie .. Have a great day :-)